# MySQL - Getting Duplicate Rows on Table Join with Relational Table when Outputting

Tags: php, mysql, join, duplicates

I am making a music site on which there will be a CMS to add new songs, and the visitor can see/play the songs on the news feed or browse/search by artist/song. Songs are referred to as tracks from here on.

The database looks as follows:

tracks

id | title | artist | year | path_mp3 | path_ogg | date_time

artists

id | artist  (I have this table because I'd like to add additional artist info later on.)

track2artist

track_id | artist_id

Some tracks have two or more artists, with those artists each having their own solo tracks as well. Therefore I'd like to keep these artists as separate entities so that users can browse to them accordingly, yet when applicable, show that multiple artists were responsible for the same song.

When I output a track on the news feed that has multiple artists, I would like to link to a page which grabs only tracks which both artists contributed to, and from that page, if the visitor clicks one of the artists, to go to the individual artist page.

http://www.discogs.com/search?q=cid+inc+and+victor+hugo&type=all

For example, if you click this link and choose the top search result, you can see the effect I'm looking for. The artist links are separate on the landing page.

What I'm getting with my current code is that tracks that have multiple entries in the track2artist table (by having multiple artists), are getting displayed multiple times. I would like each track to occur only once, yet have it still be known if there are multiple artists, and what their ids are.

I have tried including the "group by tracks.id" at the end of the sql statement, which does in fact select each statement only once. However, this fails to pick up any multiple artist_id entries in track2artist, so I have no way of passing these multiple artist ids when the user clicks.

Would I need new SQL syntax or is it in my PHP? I am trying to get away with as few database calls as possible, as I know that's what is recommended.

I appreciate any help on this. This is possibly covered elsewhere, but when searching, I was rather confused when trying to understand other examples. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

```
$conn = dbConnect('read');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks INNER JOIN track2artist ON tracks.id = track2artist.track_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
?>
<table id="feed">
    <?php
    while($track = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:;" id="playlist-add-track-id-<?php echo $track['id']; ?>">
        <img src="/assets/img/add_track.gif" class="add_track_icon"></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $track['title']; ?> by <a href="/?page=artist&artist_id=<?php echo $track['artist_id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $track['artist']; ?></a></td>
        </tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have songs with multiple authors in a different table you are going to have the tracks listed more then once. [once for each piece of data that makes the row different]

what you want returned is something like this

```
 track          artist
                artist
                artist

 track          artist
                artist

 track          artist

 track          artist
```

however mysql will only return FULL ROWS meaning for each piece of data it will return a complete row of information. to keep queries low it is best to group the information after the database has returned the info.

I would say instead of outputting right away, put this as your database parse loop

```
<?php
 while($track = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $tracklist[$track['id']]['title'] = $track['title'];
      $tracklist[$track['id']]['artists'][$track['artist_id']] = $track['artist'];
 }
```

this will crunch your array into the format you are expecting to find, btw, you will also have to iterate over the artists array with in the track array to display all the artists associated with each track.

Comment: This looks promising. Actually I just deleted the artist column from the tracks table because it is redundant. How would I modify my sql statement to also join to the artists table?

Comment: Got it: just added another INNER JOIN at the end. Got this working now. Thanks much for the quick help... Love Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

use the `DISTINCT` keyword, which will not return duplicates when joining.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tracks INNER JOIN track2artist ON tracks.id = track2artist.track_id";
```

Comment: I just copy/pasted this into my mysql terminal and it returned duplicate rows for the tracks that had multiple artists, I'm guessing because they were different based on the artist_id column... :/

Comment: then join them using the artist id not track id